# Stubbing out save methodin rails with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, stub, stubbing

I have the following action in my controller:

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @vin = @user.vins.new(params[:vin])

    if @vin.save
        # waiting for implementation
        logger.debug("here we are")
    else
        redirect_to(vins_path)
    end         
end
```

I'd like to test with with rspec.   However, I want to stub out the save operation to simulate a failure:

```
it "should send user to vins_path if there is a problem creating the VIN" do
    @vin.stub!(:save).and_return(false)
    post 'create', :vin => { :name => "Test 1", :vin => "test" }
    response.should redirect_to(vins_path)
end
```

However, the stub doesn't seem to work as the save operation is always successful.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Vin.any_instance.stub(:save).and_return(false)
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, I'm getting an undefined method 'vins' error on that statement.